# Getting Text Box Value using express.js in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

being a beginner i m trying to develop a very simple service using express in node js the aim of my service is that a simple index page taking a value and after submit it show on next page..

The Problem:
When i run it from terminal i.e. node app.js
The server start Running On port 3000
but When i execute it on browser .e.g Fire Fox it show me the Following error
"The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
cookies.
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
cookies.

The following is the code of my server App.js File

```
var express = require('express');
var service = require('./routes/service');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'your secret here' }));
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes
app.get('/', service.home);
app.post('/',service.home_post_handler);
app.get('/items', service.items);
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

Service.js (Route defined)

```
exports.home= function(req,res){
  if(typeof req.message== 'Undefined')
    res.render('home', {title:'My Service'});
  else
    res.redirect('/items');
};

exports.home_post_handler = function(req,res){
  message = req.body.message || 'Message Command is Empty';
  req.message = message;
  res.redirect('/');
}

// Just using cox in tutorial there they use it as database
/*var items = {
  WEL:{name:'Welcome Dear'}
}*/

exports.items = function(req,res){
  if(typeof req.message == 'undefined')
    res.redirect('/');
  else
    res.render('items',{title:'My Service - Message', message:req.body.message, items:items});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following middlewares have a chance to keep redirecting to each other.

```
exports.home= function(req,res){
  if(typeof req.message== 'Undefined')
    res.render('home', {title:'My Service'});
  else
    res.redirect('/items');
};

exports.items = function(req,res){
  if(typeof req.message == 'undefined')
    res.redirect('/');
  else
    res.render('items',{title:'My Service - Message', message:req.body.message, items:items});
};
```